# PRG pattern technique with input validation

Tags: php, html, forms, post, post-redirect-get

I have implemented the **Post/Redirect/Get Pattern** to avoid http post requests to be sent to the server each time the web page is reloaded, but i get a problem.

The `Welcome` message should only be displayed **once** when the password is set to `test`. In my case, it is never displayed, unless you comment out the 4th line.

If you remove that line, PRG pattern is not applied, hence form gets resubmitted on each page reload

The code below is a full working code, paste that directly in your code for testing. or [here](https://www.tehplayground.com/aTVE5poitPtmB446)

```
<?php  
$self = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
if(isset($_POST['Code2']) && ( $_POST['Code2'] == "test")) {
header('Location: '.$self, true, 303);exit; //redirection on the same page
?> <span id="welcome-msg"></span> <!-- Display welcome Message -->
<?php } ?> 

<form method="post">
 Code:<br>
<input type="text" name="Code2"> <input type="submit">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#welcome-msg").html("Welcome").fadeOut(5500);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple PoC that uses PHP sessions instead of cookies. A client session is identified by a cookie but the client has no control over the data the session stores. You could, in theory, put more sensitive data into the "welcome" message this way, although the login method is still very basic and should at least be done over HTTPS.

```html
<?php
// Start PHP session management
session_start();
$self = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

if (isset($_POST['Code2']) && $_POST['Code2'] === "test") {
  // Code is correct, flash the welcome message after redirect
  $_SESSION["flash_welcome"] = true;
  header('Location: '.$self, true, 303);
  exit;
} else if (isset($_POST['Code2']) && $_POST['Code2'] !== "test") {
  // Code was sent but is incorrect, flash the incorrect message after redirect
  $_SESSION["flash_incorrect"] = true;
  header('Location: '.$self, true, 303);
  exit;   
}
if ($_SESSION["flash_welcome"]) {
  // Display welcome message
  ?><span id="welcome-msg">Welcome</span><?php
}
if ($_SESSION["flash_incorrect"]) {
  // Display incorrect message
  ?><span id="incorrect-msg">Incorrect code</span><?php
}

// Clear flash messages
$_SESSION["flash_welcome"] = false;
$_SESSION["flash_incorrect"] = false;
?>
<form method="post">
  Code:<br><input type="text" name="Code2"> 
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$("#welcome-msg,#incorrect-msg").fadeOut(5500);</script>
```

Comment: Use `session_destroy();` at the end to clear that out of memory

Answer (score 0):

Your `<span id="welcome-msg"></span>` is located after a redirection and after an `exit()` inside an if statement
If the condition exists or not, your span will never be displayed.
You need to move it out of the "if", or add it before the redirection and  "exit()"

```
<?php  
$self = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
if(isset($_POST['Code2']) && ( $_POST['Code2']== "test")) {
    header('Location: '.$self, true, 303);  
    exit;
} ?>              
<span id="welcome-msg"></span>
<form method="post">
    Code:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Code2"> <input onclick="event.preventDefault()" type="submit">
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#welcome-msg").html("Welcome").fadeOut(5500);
</script>
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/Hf25u68JYljxkjQu

Comment: yes but if only  the code is set to `test` the message should appear. The users will enter the password then a message should appear only once. Also the from can't be submitted if you use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: PHP stops execution of anything after "exit()" syntax. When a redirect syntax is given "header()", php stop executions of anything after. And you are using both of them before displaying your "<span id="welcome-msg"></span>". This means, your div container will NEVER be displayed, and jquery will not find the requested div in the DOM as it was never there.

Comment: yes i got this, but the message should be displayed when the password is correct. It doesn't matter if the span is after the exit, even when i put it before the redirection it is not displayed

Comment: If you need to display the message, you must remove the redirection. When doing this: "header('Location: '.$self, true, 303);" the page is redirected and $_POST data do not exist anymore.
You can remove the PHP redirection, put your javascript inside the "if" statement and use a javascript redirection after 5500ms like this for example: setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = "http://example.com/someurl" }, 5500);

Comment: no, it is not a good RPG pattern technique, client should never be trusted

Comment: As said before, your div container will NEVER be displayed after a redirection and an exit(). You can do some workaround by creating a session var before redirection and then check if that session var exists: you display your div and then your remove the session var to avoid conflicts. I'll post another answear with the code in details

Comment: or maybe redirect the user if the page is reloaded for second time?